# Erro com CoordinatorLayout

Tags: java, android

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="6dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Opção de Pesq.: "
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_normal" />

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/comboOpcaoPesqCliente"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_normal" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="6dp">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edPesquisaCliente"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:hint="Digite para pesquisar"
                    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_editText" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btLimpar"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Limpar"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_normal" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerViewListaClientes"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:divider="@null"
                android:dividerHeight="0dp"
                android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
                android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
                android:scrollbars="vertical" />

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBar"
                style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Large"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center|center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                android:visibility="invisible" />

        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

adicionei isto na activity no Manifest:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

O que esta ocorrendo de errado é o seguinte:

Quando rodo a lista para baixo e a Toolbar esconde e eu clico em um EditText e o teclado se abre, depois quando fecho o teclado e rolo a lista para cima, a Toolbar simplesmente some, mas isso só acontece quando o teclado é aberto quando a Toolbar está escondida:

Foto:
Antes:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Depois:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Se você rolar a tela pra cima, a toolbar aparece ou ela continua escondida pra sempre? Não entendi também porque o `LinearLayout` está com o `behavior`, apenas o `RecyclerView` precisa tê-lo.

Comment: Desse jeito que fiz a Toolbar funciona corretamente, se eu rolar a lista para baixo a Toolbar aparece, se eu rolar a lista para cima a Toolbar  some. Só que quando a Toolbar esta escondida e eu abro o teclado e digito algo e fecho o teclado, quando rolo a lista para baixo, a Toolbar aparece, mas fica toda cinza, igual a foto que postei acima. Se eu tiro o behavior do LinearLayout e coloco no RecyclerView, o LinearLayout fica sobre o Toolbar. Imagem do behavior no RecyclerView: http://i.stack.imgur.com/UldrP.png

Comment: Rodrigo, acho que o correto é manter o behavior no `RecyclerView`. O problema nesse caso é o uso do `android:fitsSystemWindows`. Se você não utilizar o `NavigationView`, é o caso de tirar esse atributos de todas as views desse layout, que vai resolver esse problema.

Comment: Tirei o android:fitsSystemWindows e mudei o behavior do LinearLayout para o RecyclerView e o LinearLayout continuou sobre a Toolbar

Comment: Será que pode ser a versão que estou compilando? Estou usando essas:              compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'       /             compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'

Comment: Duvido muito que seja, mas é sempre bom utilizar as últimas versões (23.1.1 hoje). Vou tentar montar um exemplo aqui e reproduzir o problema pra conseguir investigar melhor.

Comment: Cara, se puder fazer isso ficarei muito agradecido. Faz tempo que estou com este problema, mas surgiu algumas coisa de mais importância para fazer no app e deixei isto de lado, agora que sobrou um tempo que estou retomando isto. Vlw. Vou editar o post principal com o XML completo

Comment: De certa forma descobri o problema. O `LinearLayout` fica por baixo do `AppBarLayout` porque pedi para tirar o behavior (o behavior é quem faz ele ficar abaixo). Retornando com o behavior no `LinearLayout` (sem o do RecyclerView), mantendo sem o atributo `fitsSystemWindows` resolve o problema?

Comment: Fiz dessa forma que você disse, ai voltou como estava antes, o LinearLayout não fica sobre a Toolbar e a Toolbar funciona perfeitamente. Mas ocorre aquele problema de o teclado ser aberto quando a Toolbar está escondida, ai quando a Toolbar volta ao rolar a lista, a Toolbar fica cinza, igual a foto do post principal

Comment: Gravei um vídeo com o que está ocorrendo:  http://sendvid.com/gffll5yj    . Repare que a Toolbar só fica cinza quando o teclado é aberto quando ela está escondida, e depois quando abro o teclado novamente ela volta a aparecer na cor normal.

Comment: Acho muito estranho, não sei se é bug da implementação do appcompat. Mas aqui eu fiz o mesmo teste (com um layout um pouco mais simples) e não deu problema. Esse layout também está bem complexo, não sei se você simplificar ele pra tentar achar a causa do problema ajuda. Olhando melhor, não acho que o toolbar esteja cinza, ele não voltou acho.

Comment: O que você me sugere para simplificar o layout? Ainda não tentei com a versão 23.1.1 , pois não tenho instalada aqui, logo que instalar vou tentar...

Comment: A primeira coisa que me veio é que tem um `LinearLayout` vertical redundante ali, aninhados. Tem algumas dimensões estranhas, tipo um cara `layout_height=wrap_content` com um filho sendo `layout_height=match_parent`, nesse caso seria legal ajustar também (não é bom ter um pai `wrap_content` e filho `match_parent`).

Comment: Alterei para a versão 23.1.1 e funcionou, era bug da versão anterior. Vlw..

Comment: Massa, poderia colocar uma resposta comentando essa solução. Pode ajudar outras pessoas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problema solucionado.

Antes estava usando essas versões:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
```

Passei a usar essas:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
```

Pelo visto é um bug da versão 22.2.0

Comment: Rodrigo, não esqueça de marcar como correta :D

Comment: Sim, fui marcar como correta e diz que só posso marcar minha própria resposta amanha haha

Comment: Blz, sem grilo :D